# Firebase dump json data

Tags: android, python, firebase

I'm no back-end developer. So perspective is always appreciated.

I have written a script which requests from an API and creates this huge JSON file I want to save in firebase, how can I accomplish this? And would it be possible to filter this json with python for example; when I add region=eu in the url this returns the objects which have Europe as region or do I absolutely need to request the entire json file and parse in my code (java android) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are a few parts to your question:

You can save JSON to Firebase and the data will be mapped to child locations:

> Using PUT, we can write a string, number, boolean, array or any JSON object to our Firebase database...When a JSON object is saved to the database, the object properties are automatically mapped to child locations in a nested fashion.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data

And for your next question:

> And would it be possible to filter this json with python for example; when I add region=eu in the url this returns the objects which have Europe as region

Looks like you should be able to jimmy something together with Firebase's filters, `startAt` and `endAt`:

> We can combine startAt and endAt to limit both ends of our query.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering

For your example you might do something like this:

```
curl 'https://yourfirebase.firebaseio.com/yourendpoint.json?orderBy="$REGION_NAME"&startAt="EU"&endAt="EU"&print=pretty'
```

> ...or do I absolutely need to request the entire json file and parse in my code (java android) ?

The facts that JSON objects are stored hierarchically in Firebase and that you can filter based on those object values makes me think you do not, in fact, have to request the entire JSON file. However, I don't have personal experience with this particular aspect of Firebase, so give it a shot!

---

As [@ackushiw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895249/ackushiw) mentions in the comments, you can also use the `equalTo` query (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo):

`curl 'https://yourfirebase.firebaseio.com/yourendpoint.json?orderBy="$REGION_NAME"&equalTo="EU"&print=pretty'`

Comment: you can also use the `equalTo` 
query:
`curl 'https://yourfirebase.firebaseio.com/yourendpoint.json?orderBy="$REGION_NAME"&equalTo="EU"&print=pretty'`

Comment: Great, hope you don't mind if I add that in to my answer?

Comment: Probably! I'd recommend researching and creating a different question for that.

Comment: @BrianKung Sorry to annoy you again, but which database do I work with RealTime Database or cloud firestore ? Especially if i'll be using cron to update my json data weekly.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore The querying section in particular

Comment: @user9132502 you'll also want to take into account of the different pricing structures of the two. Main difference is Real-Time Database is priced by bandwidth whereas Firestore is priced by Read/Writes.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you are structuring your JSON. It's generally recommended to make your JSON tree as shallow as possible since all children are loaded when you have a matching query.

**FIREBASE DATA**:

```
{
  "-id1": {
     "region": "eu" // bear in mind queries are case sensitive
     "title": "Foo"
     "nested": {
       "city": "berlin"
     }
  },
  "-id2": {
     "region": "other"
     "title": "Bar"
     "nested": {
       "city": "berlin"
     }
  },
  "-id3": {
     "region": "eu" 
     "title": "Baz"
     "nested": {
       "city": "paris"
     }
  }
}
```

Querying with (using the Android API)
`.orderByChild("region").equalTo("eu")`

would return `"-id1"` and `"-id3"`

with 
`.orderByChild("nested/city").equalTo("berlin")`

would return `"-id1"` and `"-id2"`

> The REST API Returns Unsorted Results: JSON interpreters do not enforce any ordering on the result set. While orderBy can be used in combination with startAt, endAt, limitToFirst, or limitToLast to return a subset of the data, the returned results will not be sorted. Therefore, it may be necessary to manually sort the results if ordering is important.

---

If you're using a more complex structure I recommend watching this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA

I'd also recommend using the firebase library for Android 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

And Firebase-UI, It does a lot for you. 
https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an example of saving the json my python scripts generates in the firebase database?

Comment: Thank you for all that. Is it possible to execute a python function that puts the data in the database with cron (every tuesday)?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible, you could look at Google App Engine https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ or AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html (this would require a separate cron job to fire the function)